# Can i give dynamic placeholder for Manifest file package?

Tags: android

Can i give dynamic placeholder for `Manifest` file package?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.india.hello"  //Package name is static 
    android:installLocation="internalOnly" >
```

Can we change the package `com.india.hello` to dynamic value like `${ApplicationId}`

Comment: I think no, is the requirement to replace a previous application on device?

Comment: I'm interested to know why you need to make it as dynamic?

Comment: I want to maintain different package for each flavor.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between *package name* and *application ID*.

The `package` attribute in AndroidManifest.xml is used

- as a root where generated resource IDs are (the R.java file)
- as a root against which relative component names are resolved (such as `.MainActivity`

You can specify the `applicationId` in your gradle build script. This overwrites the `package` attribute explained above but does not affect values originally derived from it. This is why you don't have to change your code every time you change the application ID in build script.

I.e. you can have classes generated in `com.example.android` but your app is installed as `com.example.android.debug` or other.

Typically you need to reference the application ID. That's accessible in the manifest as `${applicationId}` and you can use it e.g. to generate content provider authorities, such as `${applicationId}.fileprovider`.

So

> Can i give dynamic placeholder for Manifest file package?

No, and you don't want to.

> Can we change the package com.india.hello to dynamic value

You can provide different application IDs for different product flavors in the build script. Multiple apps can be installed on the same device, all of them derived from one project with single package name.